# Modify SAML attribute from IDP inside keycloak

Tags: attributes, saml, keycloak

I'm getting an SAML attribute (personal id number) following a successful IDP login.  In our keycloak implementation I fetch this using an identity provider mapper with type 'Username Template Importer' and template {ATTRIBUTE.uid}

This attribute is then used within keycloak (via user federation defined endpoints) to call other services to verify the user.  The problem I have is that this attribute is in the wrong format.  Is it possible somehow in keycloak when fetching the attribute to modify it?  Or does this need to be done within the verification service's code?

Comment: What do you mean by wrong format? Wrong type? Like string vs integer?

Comment: I get a string in the format: 123456781234 and I need it formatted like this: 12345678-1234 as that's how the key is stored in our DB.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this type of issue I would think you need to implement your own authenticator, and use that as a "Post Login Flow" on the identity provider.

So first, you have a simple attribute mapper that maps the attribute, and then map this value programmatically to the correct format in the authenticator.